# Blob animation with static background image?

Tags: css, canvas

I want to make "blob" (or Gooey) effect similar to "Canva" website. It should be much simpler and without any interaction.

I tried to use HTML5 Canvas but I am not good at it. So I tried to make it with CSS only and I make it... kind of.

```
.header:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    right: -500px;
    z-index: -999;
    background: #043d7a;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 700px;
    -webkit-animation: move 20s linear infinite;
    animation: move 20s linear infinite;
    border-radius: 70% 30% 30% 70%/60% 40% 60% 40%
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        border-radius: 70% 30% 30% 70%/60% 40% 60% 40%
    }
    25% {
        width: 1190px;
        border-radius: 72% 47% 43% 67%/54% 34% 69% 56%
    }
    50% {
        width: 1170px;
        border-radius: 72% 34% 66% 34%/54% 34% 69% 56%
    }
    75% {
        width: 1190px;
        border-radius: 72% 47% 43% 67%/37% 61% 46% 73%
    }
    100% {
        width: 1200px;
        border-radius: 70% 30% 30% 70%/60% 40% 60% 40%
    }
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        border-radius: 70% 30% 30% 70%/60% 40% 60% 40%
    }
    25% {
        width: 1210px;
        border-radius: 72% 47% 43% 67%/54% 34% 69% 56%
    }
    50% {
        width: 1150px;
        border-radius: 72% 34% 66% 34%/54% 34% 69% 56%
    }
    75% {
        width: 1170px;
        border-radius: 72% 47% 43% 67%/37% 61% 46% 73%
    }
    100% {
        width: 1200px;
        border-radius: 70% 30% 30% 70%/60% 40% 60% 40%
    }
}
```

.header element is relative and this works very well. The only problem is that blob is blue and I want static image so it looks like blob is "walking" over that image. Just watch an example on the "Canva.com" website in the header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ96q.jpg
That gooey shape is "live", it's moving around and change shape slightly, but the background image is fixed. So, I want that effect but without any interaction, just blob changing shape and moving slightly. If that is not possible with cross-browser CSS, Canvas is ok too.

Comment: *The only problem is that blob is blue and I want static image so it looks like blob is "walking" over that image* --> change the blue with an image

Comment: by *blue*, do you mean this color [#043d7a](https://www.color-hex.com/color/043d7a)?  From what I can determine from your question, I think you're pretty much there.  as @TemaniAfif mentioned, it may be that you simply need to use `background-image: src()` here and not define a color.

Comment: Problem is that if I move "blob" to the left (with left property) image moves as well. I want static image in the background and blob as, well, mask over it.

Comment: yea.. masking would be an interesting consideration.. probably would use canvas for that